# How I can update a module automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I have 2 project in Android Studio that share a module (I import in the second project the module that is in the first Project), if I change the module in the first project, in the second project is not update even pressing "Sync project with gradle files".

How to autoupdate the module in the second project, having made changes in the first project without having to import the module?

Comment: The code is not matter, I want auto update without import the module again. i dont know if is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not think that is going to work for you. I have to do the same thing every time I do some change in my library project. There is no auto sync between inter-module dependencies. Its just only in one project that you can have the gradle sync functionality.

So you will have to make your library project a running application by changing these in the build.gradle file of the module

1 ) change apply plugin: 'com.android.library' to apply plugin: 'com.android.aplication' (Be careful to match the nomanclature of the gradle plugin you use)

2) Declare application id or the default package name inside  defaultConfig { and versionCode 1, versionName "1.0" values if you have already commented them.

Make sure the app runs ok and then re-integrate it in your main project where you refer this library. Make sure to convert it back to a library before referring it.

once being imported into main project as modules, in your module Manifest files,  (Not the main project Manifest) remove this line

```
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />.
```

Otherwise app will display many launcher icons that equal to number of modules you have.

You need to use xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" namespace on top of Main project's manifest.
Then put into Application tag of Main project tools:replace="android:icon,android:theme. This will override themes and style of child modules. Leave the main project's launcher intent as it is but each and every other module's manifest file must not have .

In order to merge the manifest files put this on bottom of gradle.properties file
             manifestmerger.enabled=true 
It will merge the manifest file resources such as activities and broadcast receiver, etc..

Comment: I forgot to mention these,

Comment: Ahmm, ok i will make the changes. On the other hand. If I do another project (A third project) and modules in this project, then I import from there. Are the modules would be autoupdated in the other two projects when changing the module in the project where I made module?